# JTable with data from properties file

Tags: java, swing, properties, jtable

I have simple JTable object with 2 columns. I want to put here values from `file.properties` but I don't know how do this.

For example `file.properties` looks like:

```
some1.text1=Text1
some1.text2=Text2
some2.text1=Text_1
some2.text2=Text_2
```

And now I want to add these data to TableModel like this(it's example from swing):

```
Object rowData[][] = { { some1.text1, some2.text1 }, ... };
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would NOT create a 2 dimensional array since you may not know how many properties you have.

Instead you would create one row of data for each property and then add the row to the `DefaultTableModel`. The basic logic would be something like:

```
String columnNames = { "Column1", "Column2" };
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

for (each property pair)
{
    Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>(2);
    row.addElement( get first value );
    row.addElement( get second value );
    model.addRow( row );
}

JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this using 'new Property()'

This read my file.propertieswell but now I'm interesting something else. How can I read my file in other way, for example my file.property looks like:

```
some.1.name=...
some.1.value=...
some.2.name=...
some.2.value=...
```

I can read each of them like this

```
@ResourceBundleBean(key="some.1.name")
private String some_1_name;
@ResourceBundleBean(key="some.1.value")
private String some_1_value;
```

etc...

But if is there possibility to use only one String field for for name and value(Value is String too) OR only 1 String field to get each property some.1. some.2. etc  and get from this field name and value?

For example if my file.properties will have many item only with name/value some like:

```
some.1.name=...
some.1.value=...
...
some.200.name=...
some.200.value=...
```

I do not want to create 200 fields to do this. Is it possible?
Or if it is not possible how can I read arrays from property?
Instead of upper properties make some like this:

```
some.[1].name=n1
some.[1].value=v1
...
some.[200].name=n200
some.[200].value=v200
```

And how can I read this array to use it for output some like:

```
n1 - v1
...
n200 - v200
```